# Get some elements from an array mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In MongoDB shell version v4.4.6
the following code works perfectly.

```
db['pri-msgs'].findOne({tag:'aaa&%qqq'},{msgs:{$slice:-2}})
```

But in nodeJs mongoDB the following code doesn't work.

```
db.collection('pri-msgs').findOne({
  tag: 'aaa&%qqq'
}, {
  msgs: {
    slice: -2
  }
})
```

My document-->

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"60c4730fadf6891850db90f9"},"tag":"aaa&%qqq","msgs":[{"msg":"abc","sender":0,"mID":"ctYAR5FDa","time":1},{"msg":"bcd","sender":0,"mID":"gCjgPf85z","time":2},{"msg":"def","sender":0,"mID":"lAhc4yLr6","time":3},{"msg":"efg","sender":0,"mID":"XcBLC2rGf","time":4,"edited":true},{"msg":"fgh","sender":0,"mID":"9RWVcEOlD","time":5},{"msg":"hij","sender":0,"mID":"TJXVTuWrR","time":6},{"msg":"jkl","sender":0,"mID":"HxUuzwrYN","time":7},{"msg":"klm","sender":0,"mID":"jXEOhARC2","time":8},{"msg":"mno","sender":0,"mID":"B8sVt4kCy","time":9}]}
```

`Actually what I'm trying to do is Get last 2 itmes from msgs Array where time is greater than 'n'. Here 'n' is a number.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline) to get the results you are looking for. The steps are the following.

1. [Match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-match) the documents you want by `tag`.
2. [Unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the `msgs` array.
3. [Sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/)  descending by `msgs.time`.
4. [Limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) first 2 elements.
5. Match the `time` you are looking for using a range query.
6. [Group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) the documents back by `_id`.

Your query should look something like this:

```js
db['pri-msgs'].aggregate([
  { $match: { tag: 'aaa&%qqq' } },
  { $unwind: '$msgs' },
  {
    $sort: {
      'msgs.time': -1 //DESC
    }
  },
  { $limit: 2 },
  {
    $match: {
      'msgs.time': {
        $gt: 2 //n
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$_id',
      tag: { $first: '$tag' },
      msgs: {
        $push: { msg: '$msgs.msg', sender: '$msgs.sender', mID: '$msgs.mID', time: '$msgs.time' }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```